# PHP - storing array in one variable

Tags: php, arrays

i want to store `$user` in `$message_lnk` for using at `$content_lnk = array('chat_id' => $chatid,'text' => "$message_lnk" );`

but my snippet not work. help me please !

```
            foreach ($result as $user) {
            $user = $user['movie_lnk'];
        }
        $message_lnk = print_r($user, true);
        $content_lnk = array('chat_id' => $chatid,'text' => "$message_lnk" );
```

Comment: How exactly `it not work`?

Comment: you overwrite the value of $user on every iteration of the $result array so you would only ever get the values from the last one echoed out to screen / sent to the $content_link!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might be more like what you are expecting but this also overwrites the value on each iteration

```
foreach ($result as $user) {
    $user = $user['movie_lnk'];
    $message_lnk = print_r($user, true);
    $content_lnk = array('chat_id' => $chatid, 'text' => $message_lnk );
}
```

so, perhaps add the $content_lnk to an array?

```
$links=array();
foreach ($result as $user) {
    $user = $user['movie_lnk'];
    $message_lnk = print_r($user, true);
    $content_lnk = array('chat_id' => $chatid, 'text' => $message_lnk );
    $links[]=$content_lnk;
}
print_r( $links );
```

Comment: tanx. its work well :)

Answer (score 0):

you're not building an array with this code, you're just setting $user to the last value within $result

You should have another variable, $links and do the following within the for loop.

```
<?php
$links[]=$user['movie_lnk'];
```

And then on line 3, if you want to store the array as a string use:

```
<?php
$message_lnk=implode(", ", $links);
```

Or as an array:

```
<?php 
$message_lnk=$links;
$content_lnk=array('chat_id'=>$chat_id, 'text'=>$message_lnk)
```

Notice I removed the quotation marks around $message_lnk

Hope that helps.